# AutoResize GridView Columns' width according to their contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is there is any way to autoresize gridview columns according to their data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

Set AutoSizeMode property of the column to AllCells.

Answer (score -1):

Use the ItemStyle-Warp to False int the property list:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What are the benefits of using "ItemStyle-Wrap" over the `AutoSizeMode` property? Would this have applied at the time the question was asked, or was it introduced at sometime, or in some version, since then?